# How to rename a journaled library in ibm i 6.1?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am currently busy writing a program that renames libraries. My problem is that when I try to rename a library and it has either a default journal "QDFTJRN" or a user defined journal.

How do I go about renaming libraries containing *JRN, *JRNRCV and QDFTJRN.*DTAARA?

My current thought process is to "ENDJRNPF" and delete *JRN, *JRNRCV and do the rename of the library "RNMOBJ". After this I do a "CRTJRNRCV", "CRTJRN" and "STRJRNPF".

Answer (score 1):

That's a good plan.  You'll need to know what files are journaled before ENDJRNPF/STRJRNPF. One way is to `DSPFD FILE(yourlib/*ALL) TYPE(*ATR) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) FILEATR(*PF) OUTFILE
(QTEMP/DSPFD)` and read through that. `select phfile, phjrnl, phjrnm, phjrlb, phjrim, phjrom from dspfd where phjrnl='Y'`

There is a potential problem with libraries that are in fact SQL schemas.  Schemas are created using the SQL `create schema` statement.  They get an SQL catalogue (all those SYS... files) and the QDFTJRN and associated receiver.  It might be easier to SAVLIB to a save file, then RSTLIB to the new library name and create the journal and receiver manually.

All of this is a lot of work, I wish you luck!